# Logical expression configuration tool UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, expression, rule-engine

Recently i have a requirment from bussines for build a tool that configure our application data input like these:

if ( "field x1" equal "value 1" and "field x2" equal "value 2" ) or ("field x3" equal "value 3" ) ...
then
set value of "field y" to "value y"

now i have build the engine ( BRMS like engine ) and the UI that looks like :

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/filter-basics.html

or

http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/filter_editor.xml

but our business says that is difficult to use.

Have any idea for Logical Expression presentation and input UI different from these?

I really appreciate your help.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: My first questions to them would be: "What do you expect this to look like?" or "Why is this difficult to use?"

Comment: These is difficult to use because there is a complex rule with ( "field x1" equal "value 1" and "field x2" equal "value 2" ) or ("field x3" equal "value 3" ) or [( "field x5" equal "value 5" and "field x6" equal "value " ) or ("field x7" equal "value 7" )] .. and {  } the business have to find the root operator expression for each group these where these expression is very large and very complex.

Comment: For the first question "What do you expect this to look like?" I'm not asking for the "logical interpretation" but for the UI presantation ( design )

Comment: Have you seen the Web Rule engine?